# Replace SQL string in all tables at once

Tags: sql, replace, phpmyadmin

My goal is to add `www` to addresses, replacing `http://mywebsite.org` with `http://www.mywebsite.org` in all tables at once.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT Replace('http://mywebsite.org', 'mywebsite.org', 'www.mywebsite.org')
```

Any help?

new edit:

i try to change this in wp_option, its a option_value string:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.iemj.org' WHERE option_value = 'http://iemj.org'
```

-- doesnt change

```
 a:4:{s:25:"dashboard_recent_comments";a:1:{s:5:"items";i:5;}s:24:"dashboard_incoming_links";a:5:{s:4:"home";s:19:"http://www.iemj.org";s:4:"link";s:95:"http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?scoring=d&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.iemj.org/";s:3:"url";s:124:"http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?scoring=d&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://iemj.org/";s:5:"items";i:10;s:9:"show_date";b:0;}s:17:"dashboard_primary";a:7:{s:4:"link";s:26:"http://wordpress.org/news/";s:3:"url";s:31:"http://wordpress.org/news/feed/";s:5:"title";s:14:"WordPress Blog";s:5:"items";i:2;s:12:"show_summary";i:1;s:11:"show_author";i:0;s:9:"show_date";i:1;}s:19:"dashboard_secondary";a:7:{s:4:"link";s:28:"http://planet.wordpress.org/";s:3:"url";s:33:"http://planet.wordpress.org/feed/";s:5:"title";s:20:"Other WordPress News";s:5:"items";i:5;s:12:"show_summary";i:0;s:11:"show_author";i:0;s:9:"show_date";i:0;}}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you would add what version of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT is the command used to return information from SQL. You're seeking to UPDATE information. You have also not specified what table the information is FROM or what column it is stored in. e.g.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'http://mywebsite.org', 'http://www.mywebsite.org')
```

I recommend you backup your database before playing around in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be in Update statement to change the dataset.

If its singular it should be;

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <field_name>='http://www.mywebsite.org' WHERE <field_name> = 'http://mywebsite.org'
```

Mass Changing to add 'www' after 'http://';

Please do back up before you do this, especially you rely on this dataset

```
 UPDATE <table_name> SET <field_name>=Replace(<field_name>, replace(<field_name>, 'http://', ''), 'www.'+replace(<field_name>, 'http://', '')) WHERE <field_name> LIKE 'http://%'
```

[Source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-find-replace-text/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old and this question may have a duplicate by now but I found/use this from time to time for similar reasons so thought I would share. Bit slow for larger databases but works great IMO. I definitely would recommend you wrap in BEGIN/ROLLBACK TRANSACTION first though to be sure it works/is safe first:
https://gist.github.com/1e76349ce8fa0d60459b58394999d749

Comment: am I getting an error (near 'BEGIN TRANSACTION ) because the link says MSSQL tips, although the question is marked with phpmyadmin, which suggests MySQL?